# Use MenuItem Value as CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following MenuItem which comes from a Menu (not a ContextMenu):

```
<MenuItem DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Header="Teams"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Teams,
                                Source={StaticResource Container}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OpenTeamPage}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ???}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```

How can I pass the selected item (a Team from the ItemsSource) as a CommandParameter to my Viewmodel? I've done some research but I can't find a way to get the selected item in this situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the clicked menuitem context then

```
<MenuItem DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Header="Teams"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Teams,
                                Source={StaticResource Container}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OpenTeamPage}"
                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to send anything as a parameter.

Comment: are you getting any binding errors in output window? anyways you can use the updated answer..in that way the whole eventargs will be sent as a parameter and you can find the OriginalSource.DataContext in your command handler

Comment: I'm not able to access DataContext from OriginalSource. OriginalSource is as far as it goes.

Comment: you will have to typecast it `MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem` and then `item.DataContext` will give you DataContext